# Hide/ show div outline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i show and hide div outline? I want the content inside the div to display at all times but the outline of the div display only on mouseover.

```js
function show_sidebar() {
  document.getElementById('boxes').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hide_sidebar() {
  document.getElementById('boxes').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```css
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" onMouseOver="show_sidebar()" onMouseOut="hide_sidebar()">

  <div class="container5" id="boxes">some thing</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `CSS` , `:hover` , applying the `styles` like `border`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is by using just CSS:

```
#boxes {
    border-color: transparent;
}

#wrapper:hover #boxes {
    border-color: red;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 160px; /* resized it to fit inside the screen */
  height: 200px; /* resized it to fit inside the screen */
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#boxes {
    border-color: transparent;
}

#wrapper:hover #boxes {
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container5" id="boxes">some thing</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to set the **`border-color`** property to **`transparent`** on **`mouseout`** and back to **`red`** on **`mouseover`**:

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').onmouseover = function () {
  document.getElementById('boxes').style.borderColor = "red";
}

document.getElementById('wrapper').onmouseout = function () {
  document.getElementById('boxes').style.borderColor = "transparent";
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#wrapper").hover(function() {
  $("#boxes").css("border-color", "red");
},
function() {
  $("#boxes").css("border-color", "transparent");
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$("#wrapper").hover(function() {
  $("#boxes").css("border-color", "red");
},
function() {
  $("#boxes").css("border-color", "transparent");
});
```

```css
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 160px; /* resized it to fit inside the screen */
  height: 200px; /* resized it to fit inside the screen */
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container5" id="boxes">some thing</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a separate class to conditionally toggle it, or use the `:hover` property. In the interest of JavaScript, I'll show the former. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h8c33x9d/

CSS

```
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.my-border {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function show_sidebar() {
    $('#boxes').addClass('my-border');
}

function hide_sidebar() {
     $('#boxes').removeClass('my-border');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript for that, as suggested by @KarthikeyanSekar, you only need a :hover effect to your `container` element.

An example to help you visualize can be found on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/8evLub5v/), but essentially it goes like this:

The css:

```
/* Remove the border from the .container5 style */
.container5 {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 220px;
  height: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add only the border when the mouse is hover it */

.container5:hover  {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

And the HTML remains the same, only removing the javascript binds:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container5" id="boxes">some thing</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Change border to transparent */

 .container5 {
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 220px;
        height: 320px;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    /*Add border color*/

    .container5:hover {
         border: 1px solid red;
    }
```